# How to decode this error? I'm using Google API for translation of a list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to decode this error? I'm using Google API for translation of a list using Python:

```
from googletrans import Translator

import json

#intentional conversion

translator=Translator()

z=[]

translations=translator.translate(['
ik ben goed','guten tag','das ist ein junge'], dest='en')

possible_json_string = str(translations) 

possible_json_string = '{}' #sanity check with simplest json

possible_json_string = translations #why convert to string at all?

possible_json_string = translations.decode('utf-8') 

for translation in translations:
    print(translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text)
    z.append(translation.text)
```

Comment: What's the error? What output are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with `possible_json_string`. All you need is the following code:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator=Translator()

translations=translator.translate(['ik ben goed','guten tag','das ist ein junge'], dest='en')

z = [] # assuming you'll use this list further down the line
for translation in translations:
        print(translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text)
        z.append(translation.text)
```

Output:

```
ik ben goed  ->  I'm good
guten tag  ->  good day
das ist ein junge  ->  this is a boy
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that *translations* is a list which do not have decode() function. Actually you do not need this step as in python3 all strings are automatically Unicode.
If you want to apply a function all element of a list you can use map, for example:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.text.upper(), translations))
```

Comment: The problem is that it shows a json decode error,How do we solve that error?